# Variables get overwritten when concatenated

Tags: bash, shell, unix, string-concatenation

I wrote this little bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
runDirectory="/mnt/sequences_tmp/melody_rnn/logdir/run_"
currName=$1
magenta1="bazel run //magenta/models/melody_rnn:melody_rnn_train -- --config=attention_rnn --run_dir="
echo $magenta1
magenta2="$magenta1$runDirectory"
echo $magenta2
magenta3="$magenta2$currName"
echo $magenta3
```

so that, if I start the script with the parameter "music" the output should be as follows:

```
bazel run //magenta/models/melody_rnn:melody_rnn_train -- --config=attention_rnn --run_dir=

bazel run //magenta/models/melody_rnn:melody_rnn_train -- --config=attention_rnn --run_dir=/mnt/sequences_tmp/melody_rnn/logdir/run_

bazel run //magenta/models/melody_rnn:melody_rnn_train -- --config=attention_rnn --run_dir=/mnt/sequences_tmp/melody_rnn/logdir/run_music
```

but the output I really get is:

```
bazel run //magenta/models/melody_rnn:melody_rnn_train -- --config=attention_rnn --run_dir=

/mnt/sequences_tmp/melody_rnn/logdir/run_ody_rnn_train -- --config=attention_rnn --run_dir=

musicsequences_tmp/melody_rnn/logdir/run_ody_rnn_train -- --config=attention_rnn --run_dir=
```

As you can see, instead of appending the next variable/text it instead is added to the front of the last used variable, overwriting the old variable in the progress.

Does anyone know what my error could be? I haven't found any similar questions on here yet (sadly)

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://tio.run/##XY/BCoMwDIbvPkXXeZWg3ga97bxXkFozLdh0ayvMvXxXYd1EyCH583/5SS/9FOP5BL0m6NPAqlfhFrpqhypYtwoOhgJ4fC5ICn0XzAMMznZYO0cEsx0H7SAhHS/U4txNGhRlXRg5IgVZC97LN84sORjAVwVjB5z97tDl33bBSU2sqlIpS3c9ChlCwrSlbZ/kLS7FCl6gmiwrc1hObQT/aeX@nQPQZKD9A02Z3ziY2xg/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like your variables contain `\r` (carriage return, 0x0D) somewhere. You can pipe the output into `xxd` (or any other hex dump tool) to confirm.

Was your script saved in DOS format?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you
that was it.

I already did that a while ago but I think I mistakenly added the \r again when creating a new file